# Async button event for loops in python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to run a tic_tac_toe game where i play agains't an intelligent agent, but i'm stuck in the part where the main loop has to wait for a button to be pressed to continue with the logic.

```
# Variáveis globais
player_id = 0
board = [''] * 9
human_action = None
human_action_event = asyncio.Event()

def handle_agent_click(action):
    global board, buttons
    
    board[action] = 'X'
    buttons[action].description = 'X'

def handle_button_click(button):
    global board, human_action, human_action_event
  
    index = button.index
    if board[index] == '':
        board[index] = 'O'
        button.description = 'O'
        human_action = index
        human_action_event.set()  

async def player_turn():
    global human_action, human_action_event

    while human_action is None:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    
    action = human_action
    human_action = None
    human_action_event.clear()  # Limpa o evento para ser usado novamente
    return action
```

these functions respectively handle the machine choice, what happens when clicking on a field and the player's turn

```
async def main():
    time_step = env.reset()
    while not time_step.last():
        player_id = time_step.observations["current_player"]
        if player_id == 0:
            # Ação do agente treinado com Q-Learning
            agent_output = agents[0].step(time_step, is_evaluation=True)
            action = agent_output.action
            handle_agent_click(action)
    
        else:
            action = await player_turn()
        
        time_step = env.step([action])
        print(env.get_state)
        print(time_step.rewards)

await main()
```

main loop